# Why are those very similar languages in a different complexity class?

Tags: complexity-theory, turing-machines, automata, finite-automata

i am having a real time understand why the following two languages are in two different complexity classes(the first is NP-Hard and the second is in P). tried to look online at various resources and lecture notes/books, but couldn't find a reason for it. the languages are:

1.$NONEMPTY-INTER_{DFA}\:=\:\left\{<A_1,...,A_k> |\:A_1,...,A_k\:are\:DFAS\:and\:L\left(A_1\right)\cap...\:\cap L\left(A_k\right)\:\ne \varnothing \right\}$

2.$NONDISJOINT_{DFA}\:=\:\left\{<A,B> |\:A\:and\:B\:are\:DFAS\:and\:L\left(A\right)\:\cap L\left(b\right)\:\ne \varnothing \right\}$

why is the second can be run in a polynomial time on a turing machine, and the first can not? would really appreciate an explanation for this.

Comment: Have you tried _proving_ either claim?

Answer (score 4):

It's because the running time to test $k$ DFAs, each of size $n$, is something like $\Theta(n^k)$.  This is polynomial when $k$ is fixed (like 2), but exponential when $k$ is not fixed (e.g., when $k=n$, you get something like $n^n$).

(We don't actually know for sure what the best running time for that is, but we suspect it's something like that; and that will explain why those similar-sounding problems have different complexity classes.  Likewise, we don't actually know for sure that P is a different complexity class from NP, but we suspect it is.)

Comment: You need a $\Theta$ there. ;)

Comment: @Raphael Theta here would mean that there doesn't exist algorithm that can test it faster, but it is possible to test in c*k time in the best case.

Comment: @Evil No, it would mean that the _problem space_ is truly that huge, preventing simple algorithms from working. D.W. says nothing about a complexity lower bound, which we don't know.